# Runtime error (func=(main), adr=9): Divide by zero

Tags: runtime, divide-by-zero

I am getting below error. The script curl the provided url and compare it with the previous curl. Several tests can be made, the default one is calculating how many percentage of code have been changed since last check

error

> Runtime error (func=(main), adr=9): Divide by zero ./check_defacement.sh: line 145: [: -ge: unary operator expected ./check_defacement.sh: line 151: [: -ge: unary operator expected

code

```
if [ "$int_per" -ge "$int_critical" ]; then 
    OUTPUT="CRITICAL - $int_per% code changed since last check | $int_per%" 
    STATE=$STATE_CRITICAL 
    cp $dump_dir/check_defacement_"$url" $dump_dir/dump_CRITICAL_date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S"_"$url" 
fi 
if [ "$int_per" -ge "$int_warning" ]; then 
    OUTPUT="WARNING - $int_per% code changed since last check | $int_per%" 
    STATE=$STATE_WARNING 
    cp $dump_dir/check_defacement_"$url" $dump_dir/dump_WARNING_date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S"_"$url" 
else 
    OUTPUT="OK - $int_per% code changed since last check | $int_per%" 
    STATE=$STATE_OK 
fi
```

Comment: error --->Runtime error (func=(main), adr=9): Divide by zero
./check_defacement.sh: line 145: [: -ge: unary operator expected
./check_defacement.sh: line 151: [: -ge: unary operator expected

Comment: code -->if [ "$int_per" -ge "$int_critical" ]; then
OUTPUT="CRITICAL - $int_per% code changed since last check | $int_per%"
STATE=$STATE_CRITICAL
cp $dump_dir/check_defacement_"$url" $dump_dir/dump_CRITICAL_`date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S"`_"$url"
fi

if [ "$int_per" -ge "$int_warning" ]; then
OUTPUT="WARNING - $int_per% code changed since last check | $int_per%"
STATE=$STATE_WARNING
cp $dump_dir/check_defacement_"$url" $dump_dir/dump_WARNING_`date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S"`_"$url"
else
OUTPUT="OK - $int_per% code changed since last check | $int_per%"
STATE=$STATE_OK
fi

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code there.